# SearchHost service not found

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

A few weeks back my Windows search suddenly stopped working. It opens and slowly loads when I click on it but then crashes immediately. I did try making another account and search works fine in it but not on my original one. Fixes I have tried yet:

1. Deleted the Search folder from the registry as suggested on a Microsoft Forums page
2. Reset Cortana
3. Reinstalled Cortana
4. Re-registered all Microsoft Store apps
5. Rebuilt the search index
6. Updated Windows to the latest version
7. Running the Windows Search troubleshooter
8. Restarted the Windows Search Processes

Now, while trying the last fix, I noticed something strange. According to multiple articles, I should've had a "SearchHost" service running. But when I checked for it in services, it is nowhere to be found! It isn't even visible in the details tab of the task manager! Is this service being missing the cause of the issue? If yes, how do I bring it back?

P.S. I'm using Windows 10.

Edit- Not even the last fix was able to change anything and the issue persists.

Comment: Did it work correctly after the last fix? Some info about the crashes will help.

Comment: @harrymc it didn't work, it still crashes. Firstly, the search box expands quite a while after I click on it, and it keeps loading for some time after which it shows the tabs on top named "Apps", "Documents", etc. while being unresponsive all the time, after which it crashes (the search box collapses again and after a second the search box disappears from the taskbar only to appear again after a few seconds).

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Ran both the commands, and search still refuses to work.

Comment: To return Windows to a known state, you will then need to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Strangely, adding a new user fixed this for me. I was doing this because according to what I've read, this is often a user-specific issue. But when I then went back to my original user, it worked again as well.

Comment: @John I also created a new user, and search was working perfectly fine for that user. I ended up resetting Windows, since I wanted a clean install anyway.